# Web API OData $expand doesn't return complex types

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

Domain model:

```
public class Course
{
   public int CourseId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<TeeSet> TeeSets { get; set; }
}
public class TeeSet
{
    public int TeeSetId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public CourseRating MensRating { get; set; }
}
```

The following query does not include the CourseRating complex type when Courses are expanded to include TeeSets.
GET /api/courses?$expand=TeeSets

```
public class CoursesController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Course> Get()
    {
        return _uow.Courses.GetAll();
    }
}
```

The JSON serialized result does not include the MensRating complex type (CourseRating):

```
[
  {
"teeSets": [
  {
    "teeSetId": 1,
    "courseId": 7
  },
  {
    "teeSetId": 2,
    "courseId": 7
  }
   ],
   "courseId": 7,
  }
]
```

However, a quick test against the DbContext returns the CourseRating complex type on TeeSets like I would expect:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_Course_With_TeeSets()
{
    using (CoursesContext ctx = new CoursesContext())
    {
        var courses = ctx.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseId == 7).Include(x => x.TeeSets).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Entity Framework 6 and Web API 2 used.

Answer (score 1):

You should expand `MensRating` as well like this, `GET /api/courses?$expand=TeeSets/MensRating`

When we build an implicit EDM model for supporting `QueryableAttribute` with `ApiController`, we treat every type as an entity type to get around the OData V3 limitation that complex types cannot refer to entity types. And, this means that you have to expand explicitly every non primitive type.

Comment: Yeah I tried this, but a NotSupportedException is thrown.  "Cannot compare elements of type 'StatTracker.Domain.CourseRating'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported."  Looks like this only happens when the containing entity is included via $expand, as another entity that contains the CourseRating complex type works fine with a GET or POST.

Answer (score 0):

Add [AutoExpand](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-15-autoexpand-attribute) on `MensRating` Property can make this work.