# How to access properties of complex type in OData

Tags: odata

How can we form an OData query to access the `Name` property of complex property `ProductDetails` in the `ProductDTO` class?

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ProductDetails ProductDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Discount { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturedDate { get; set; }
}
```

This query gives me ProductDetails:

```
/Products?$select=ProductDetails
```

> {"@odata.context":"http://localhost:59909/$metadata#Products(ProductDetails)","value":[{"ProductDetails":{"Name":"Laptop","Price":"100299","Discount":"1000","ManufacturedDate":"12:01:2016
>   09:30:875"}}]}

Comment: Are you looking for "/Products?$expand=ProductDetails($select=Name)"?

Comment: Yes, but this does not work as ProductDetails is not a navigation property.

Comment: Looks like: Should work with $expand, but 'not supported' is thrown by the implementation. That's a V3 ref though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137681/web-api-odata-expand-doesnt-return-complex-types

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690408/how-to-select-only-odata-child-elements), this isn't possible for a $select. However, it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve from your question so I thought I would post this in case it helps. For a single object, you can get the value of a nested property like this, here is an example using the TripPin example OData service: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/Airports('KLAX')/Location/Address/$value Here, the `Location` property is a complex type and we are getting just the value of the `Address` property on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $expand clause

In my situation i had to add a complexType first:

```
builder.ComplexType<BalanceSheet>();
```

Additionally I found that different query should be used to get the complex type on UI

Instead of calling http://url/api/AccountDetails?$select=name,accountNumber,balance another url should be used:
http://url/api/AccountDetails?$select=name,accountNumber,balance&$expand=balance

you can only see complex properties like balance via $expand

Also, important to have $expand feature turned on. To do that add it before you add the edm model:

```
endpoints.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", this.GetEdmModel());
```

See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476645/2050539